# python, sort descending dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I'm trying to sort a dataframe by descending.
I put 'False' in the ascending argument, but my order is still ascending.

My code is:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

d = {'one':[2,3,1,4,5],
     'two':[5,4,3,2,1],
     'letter':['a','a','b','b','c']}

df = DataFrame(d)

test = df.sort(['one'], ascending=[False])
```

but the output is

```
  letter  one  two
2      b    1    3
0      a    2    5
1      a    3    4
3      b    4    2
4      c    5    1
```

Comment: Your code actually gives the desired results on pandas version 0.14.1, so you may want to upgrade if possible.

Comment: Since this question refers to syntax which has worked fine since 0.14.1, (and was a fairly obvious typo before that), probably should close as not-an-issue.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Edit: This is out of date, see @Merlin's answer.

`[False]`, being a nonempty *list*, is not the same as `False`. You should write:

```
test = df.sort('one', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Just to gently point to the answers below to work with latest Pandas version.

Comment: @merlin here,  look at my Answer.. SO has dropped it to the bottom.

Answer (score 98):

New syntax (either):

```
 test = df.sort_values(['one'], ascending=[False])
 test = df.sort_values(['one'], ascending=[0])
```

Comment: You can do this for multiple columns too: test = df.sort_values(['one','two'], ascending=[0,0])

Answer (score 25):

For pandas 0.17 and above, use this :

```
test = df.sort_values('one', ascending=False)
```

Since 'one' is a series in the pandas data frame, hence pandas will not accept the arguments in the form of a list.

Comment: I seriously doubt that "hence pandas will not accept the arguments in the form of a list." is true. It does accept `ascending=[False]` on pandas 0.19. Could you elaborate?

Comment: BTW, since typing "ascending=False" is a lot to type and I use it a lot, `sort_values('one')[::-1]` will work if you take the performance hit.

Answer (score 4):

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

d = {'one':[2,3,1,4,5],
 'two':[5,4,3,2,1],
 'letter':['a','a','b','b','c']}

df = DataFrame(d)

test = df.sort_values(['one'], ascending=False)
test
```

Answer (score 0):

from pandas import DataFrame import pandas as pd

d = {'one':[2,3,1,4,5], 'two':[5,4,3,2,1], 'letter':['a','a','b','b','c']}

df = DataFrame(d)

#check below statement

df.groupby(["one"]).count().sort_values("one", ascending=False)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

I don't think you should ever provide the `False` value in square brackets (ever), also the column values when they are more than one, then only they are provided as a list! Not like `['one']`.

```
test = df.sort_values(by='one', ascending = False)
```

Comment: Use you square brackets, because you might need to sort multiple columns. Look at OP question.