# pandas nlargest is returning more than n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
            name      value 
 date   
 2016-05-01 kelly      20  
 2016-05-05 john       12  
 2016-05-05 sarah      25  
 2016-05-05 george     3  
 2016-05-05 tom        40  
 2016-05-07 kara       24  
 2016-05-07 jane       90  
 2016-05-07 sally      39  
 2016-05-07 sam        28
```

I want to get the top 3 rows (according to value) preferably per date. 
I'm expecting something like this:

```
            name      value 
 date   
 2016-05-01 kelly      20  
 2016-05-05 john       12  
 2016-05-05 sarah      25  
 2016-05-05 tom        40  
 2016-05-07 jane       90  
 2016-05-07 sally      39  
 2016-05-07 sam        28
```

but I'm ok also with this:

```
            name      value 
 date   
 2016-05-05 tom        40  
 2016-05-07 jane       90  
 2016-05-07 sally      39
```

I tried `df.nlargest(3, 'value')` but I get this weird result:

```
         name        value 
 date       
 2016-05-01 kelly      20  
 2016-05-01 kelly      20  
 2016-05-01 kelly      20  
 2016-05-05 tom        40  
 2016-05-05 tom        40  
 2016-05-05 tom        40  
 2016-05-05 sarah      25  
 2016-05-05 sarah      25  
 2016-05-05 sarah      25  
 2016-05-07 kara       24  
 2016-05-07 kara       24  
 ...
 2016-05-07 sally      39  
 2016-05-07 sally      39  
 2016-05-07 jane       90  
 2016-05-07 jane       90  
 2016-05-07 jane       90
```

I tried running it day by day:
`[df.ix[day].nlargest(3, 'value') for day in df.index.unique()]`

but I got the same problem (each name is duplicated 3 times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, this will get the job done:

```
df.sort_values('value', ascending=False).groupby(level=0).head(3).sort_index()
```

Comment: Thanks! so groupby(level=0) + sorting got the results per date just as I needed. I guess nlargest isn't usable in this use case

Answer (score 0):

## Use [`[:n]`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) slice of [`sort_values()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) result

Use [`sort_values()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) in [descending mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989227/2087463) and take the [first `n` results in a slice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), then use [`sort_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to keep the days [monotonically increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

```
import pandas as pd
import cStringIO

df  = pd.read_table(cStringIO.StringIO('''
 date   name      value 
 2016-05-01 kelly      20  
 2016-05-05 john       12  
 2016-05-05 sarah      25  
 2016-05-05 george     3  
 2016-05-05 tom        40  
 2016-05-07 kara       24  
 2016-05-07 jane       90  
 2016-05-07 sally      39  
 2016-05-07 sam        28 
'''), sep=' *', index_col=0, engine='python')

print 'Original DataFrame:'
print df
print

df_top3 = df.sort_values('value', ascending=False)[:3].sort_index()
print 'Top 3 Largest value DataFrame:'
print df_top3
print
```

---

```
Original DataFrame:
              name  value
date                     
2016-05-01   kelly     20
2016-05-05    john     12
2016-05-05   sarah     25
2016-05-05  george      3
2016-05-05     tom     40
2016-05-07    kara     24
2016-05-07    jane     90
2016-05-07   sally     39
2016-05-07     sam     28

Top 3 Largest value DataFrame:
             name  value
date                    
2016-05-05    tom     40
2016-05-07   jane     90
2016-05-07  sally     39
```