# DataFrame sorting based on a function of multiple column values

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

Based on [python, sort descending dataframe with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988873/python-sort-descending-dataframe-with-pandas):

Given:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

d = {'x':[2,3,1,4,5],
     'y':[5,4,3,2,1],
     'letter':['a','a','b','b','c']}

df = DataFrame(d)
```

df then looks like this:

```
df:
      letter    x    y
    0      a    2    5
    1      a    3    4
    2      b    1    3
    3      b    4    2
    4      c    5    1
```

I would like to have something like:

```
f = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
test = df.sort(f('x', 'y'))
```

This should order the complete dataframe with respect to the sum of the squared values of column 'x' and 'y' and give me:

```
test:
      letter    x    y
    2      b    1    3
    3      b    4    2
    1      a    3    4
    4      c    5    1
    0      a    2    5
```

Ascending or descending order does not matter. Is there a nice and simple way to do that? I could not yet find a solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
df.loc[(df.x ** 2 + df.y ** 2).sort_values().index]
```

after [How to sort pandas dataframe by custom order on string index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012525/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-by-custom-order-on-string-index/50012638)

Comment: Thank you this is a realy nice solution! The index of the sorted data is used in combination with iloc. This is neat. No further column is needed.

Comment: That indeed look like the correct approach, on the other hand you should use `.loc` instead of `.iloc` because this wouldn't work with most indexes (it will only work with indexes like `list(range(n))`. I'll add an alternative this just in case.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62624996/1720199) using `iloc` with `argsort` which is very similar to this strategy.

Answer (score 35):

You can create a temporary column to use in sort and then drop it:

```
df.assign(f = df['one']**2 + df['two']**2).sort_values('f').drop('f', axis=1)
Out: 
  letter  one  two
2      b    1    3
3      b    4    2
1      a    3    4
4      c    5    1
0      a    2    5
```

Comment: this seems to be the best way to go, but it sorta sucks... it would be way more elegant to pass a lambda function into `sort_values`, the same way you'd do that for python's native `sorted()` call

Comment: @AlexSpangher, looks like we still don't have this feature supported yet for now, 2020 Feb :-(

Comment: The advantage of python is that when it doesn't exist you can just [add the method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62624996/1720199).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to create a new column and then sorting on that. I cannot comment on the original post, so i am just posting my solution.

```
df['c'] = df.a**2 + df.b**2
df = df.sort_values('c')
```

Comment: The "problem" with this solution is that it actually creates another column which is not the exact goal here (input and output column should be the same).

Answer (score 1):

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

d = {'one':[2,3,1,4,5],
     'two':[5,4,3,2,1],
     'letter':['a','a','b','b','c']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#f = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
array = []
for i in range(5):
    array.append(df.ix[i,1]**2 + df.ix[i,2]**2)
array = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = ['Sum of Squares'])
test = pd.concat([df,array],axis = 1, join = 'inner')
test = test.sort_index(by = "Sum of Squares", ascending = True).drop('Sum of Squares',axis =1)
```

Just realized that you wanted this:

```
    letter  one  two
2      b    1    3
3      b    4    2
1      a    3    4
4      c    5    1
0      a    2    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61239173/1720199) is to use `argsort` which returns the indexes permutation directly:

```py
f = lambda r: r.x**2 + r.y**2
df.iloc[df.apply(f, axis=1).argsort()]
```

I think using `argsort` better translates the idea than a regular `sort` (we don't care about the value of this computation, only about the resulting indexes).

It could also be interesting to patch the DataFrame to add this functionality:

```py
def apply_sort(self, *, key):
    return self.iloc[self.apply(key, axis=1).argsort()]

pd.DataFrame.apply_sort = apply_sort
```

We can then simply write:

```py
>>> df.apply_sort(key=f)

   x  y letter
2  1  3      b
3  4  2      b
1  3  4      a
4  5  1      c
0  2  5      a
```

Comment: since you do a row-wise apply here wouldnt this be trading a fair bit of performance on any vectorized operation compared to andrewkittredge's method? Does the sort vs argsort offset these concerns?