# How to sort a pandas dataframe by a custom order on a string index

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, indexing, categorical-data

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2967, 5335, 13950, 6141, 6169],
                   'Player': ['Cedric Hunter', 'Maurice Baker',
                              'Ratko Varda', 'Ryan Bowen', 'Adrian Caldwell'],
                   'Year': [1991, 2004, 2001, 2009, 1997],
                   'Age': [27, 25, 22, 34, 31],
                   'Tm': ['CHH', 'VAN', 'TOT', 'OKC', 'DAL'],
                   'G': [6, 7, 60, 52, 81]})


df.set_index('Player', inplace=True)
```

It shows:

```
Out[128]:

                 Age   G   Tm  Year     id
Player
Cedric Hunter     27   6  CHH  1991   2967
Maurice Baker     25   7  VAN  2004   5335
Ratko Varda       22  60  TOT  2001  13950
Ryan Bowen        34  52  OKC  2009   6141
Adrian Caldwell   31  81  DAL  1997   6169
```

How can I sort by the index ('Player') using some arbitrary order? For example, as in the following.

```
reorderlist = ['Maurice Baker',
               'Adrian Caldwell',
               'Ratko Varda',
               'Ryan Bowen',
               'Cedric Hunter']
```

Comment: So you want it to be in order like it ordered in list `reorderlist`?

Comment: The 'right' way for pandas to implement this is to allow Categoricals as indices as R does; currently pandas doesn't, it gives error.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just `reindex`

```
df.reindex(reorderlist)
Out[89]: 
                 Age   G   Tm  Year     id
Player                                    
Maurice Baker     25   7  VAN  2004   5335
Adrian Caldwell   31  81  DAL  1997   6169
Ratko Varda       22  60  TOT  2001  13950
Ryan Bowen        34  52  OKC  2009   6141
Cedric Hunter     27   6  CHH  1991   2967
```

Update info you have multiple players with same name

```
out = df.iloc[pd.Categorical(df.index,reorderlist).argsort()]
```

Comment: Hello , i have tried this players  am getting as recorderlist but  all other values ara NAN. I want exactly as above with values

Comment: This does not work when there are players having the same name.

Comment: @DiegoFMedina check the update

Answer (score 11):

As of Pandas 1.1 [DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) has a `key` param that takes a callable to control sorting. So you could use an approach like the following:

```py
def sorter(column):
    reorder = [
        "Maurice Baker",
        "Adrian Caldwell",
        "Ratko Varda",
        "Ryan Bowen",
        "Cedric Hunter",
    ]
    # This also works:
    # mapper = {name: order for order, name in enumerate(reorder)}
    # return column.map(mapper)
    cat = pd.Categorical(column, categories=reorder, ordered=True)
    return pd.Series(cat)

df_sorted = df.sort_values(by="Player", key=sorter)
```

There may be some practical differences between using `pd.Categorical` and the `column.map` alternative I put in the comments. For example, see these [caveats](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-memory). I'm showing both for completeness. I also haven't tested how this compares performance-wise to the current accepted solution that uses `df.reindex`. The best approach might be different when you have a `MultiIndex` in play too.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes! Some wear scarves, apparently!

Answer (score 4):

To get a custom sort-order on your list of strings, declare it as a categorical and manually specify that order in a sort:

```
player_order = pd.Categorical([ 'Maurice Baker', 'Adrian Caldwell','Ratko Varda' ,'Ryan Bowen' ,'Cedric Hunter'],
              ordered=True)
```

This is since pandas does not yet allow Categoricals as indices: `df.set_index(keys=player_order, inplace=True)` `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Categorical'`

So you'll want to do a manual custom sort using `df.sort_index(level=player_order)`

Comment: Please give a solution, not '...' dots

Comment: @jean-loup: I already gave the solution here, but to be 200% clear: `df.sort_index(level=player_order)`

Answer (score 1):

If there are more than one columns that need to be sort, in my experience, I use `map` to convert `string` value to `number`. Then use `sort_values`:

```
# Step 1/3: create dictionary to convert any string to number
convert_dict = {'Maurice Baker':1,
                'Adrian Caldwell':2,
                'Ratko Varda':3} # You can start filling till the end

# Step 2/3: Create column `new` that mapping from `Player`:
df['new'] = df['Player'].map(convert_dict)

# Step 3/3: sort
df.sort_values(by=['new'], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['new'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort in arbirtary order while not including blank rows I found `df.filter` to work while testing out [BENYS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50012638/7174121) . It sorts as desired, ignores missing keys like `df.reindex`, but helpfully does not include empty rows for keys that have no data.

```
df.filter(reorderlist, axis=0)

                    id  Year  Age   Tm   G
Player                                    
Maurice Baker     5335  2004   25  VAN   7
Adrian Caldwell   6169  1997   31  DAL  81
Ratko Varda      13950  2001   22  TOT  60
Ryan Bowen        6141  2009   34  OKC  52
Cedric Hunter     2967  1991   27  CHH   6

#Extra keys dont add empty rows, missing keys ignored
reorderlist.append('LeBron James')
reorderlist.remove('Adrian Caldwell')
df.filter(reorderlist, axis=0)

                  id  Year  Age   Tm   G
Player                                  
Maurice Baker   5335  2004   25  VAN   7
Ratko Varda    13950  2001   22  TOT  60
Ryan Bowen      6141  2009   34  OKC  52
Cedric Hunter   2967  1991   27  CHH   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I've found is to just pass the list to `.loc`, but this won't work if the index is not unique.

```
df = df.loc[reorderlist, :]
```