# Pandas create histogram with custom sort order

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, sorting, histogram, bar-chart

I am trying to create a histogram of education. However, my data is such that the `edu` variable is categorical: `'10', '11', '12', 'GED', etc.`. I want a histogram that goes in that order `'10', '11', '12', 'GED', '13', etc.`

My two approaches are:

1: Use `pd.DataFrame.hist` with a new variable that maps `edu` to a numeric `edunum` variable. However, I am then having trouble getting the original `edu` lables on the histogram

2: Use `pd.Series(list(profile.['edu'])).value_counts().plot(kind="bar")`. However, I am having trouble sorting the bar order correctly.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012525/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-by-custom-order-on-string-index/50012638#50012638

Comment: Ah sorry about that - didn't see that one. Asked today, too! Thanks @wen

Comment: No worry , happy coding