# Perform value counts in Python/Pandas on one column, but return values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, count, row

In Python, Im trying to perform value_counts on a Pandas column. I can get that to work, but I can't figure out how to get some of the other associated columns.
The code:

```
import pandas as pd

myframe = pd.DataFrame({"Server":["Server_1","Server_1","Server_1","Server_1","Server_1","Server_2","Server_2","Server_2","Server_2","Server_3","Server_3","Server_3","Server_3","Server_3"], 
"CVE_ID":["CVE-2017-1111","CVE-2017-1112","CVE-2017-1113","CVE-2017-1114","CVE-2017-1115","CVE-2017-1111","CVE-2017-1112","CVE-2017-1113","CVE-2017-1114","CVE-2017-1113","CVE-2017-1114","CVE-2017-1115","CVE-2017-1116","CVE-2017-1117"],
"VulnName":["Java Update 1","Java Update 2","Java Update 3","Adobe 1","Chrome 1","Java Update 1","Java Update 2","Java Update 3","Adobe 1","Java Update 3","Adobe 1","Chrome 1","Chrome 2","Chrome 3"],
"ServerOwner":["Alice","Alice","Alice","Alice","Alice","Bob","Bob","Bob","Bob","Carol","Carol","Carol","Carol","Carol"]})

print "The dataframe: \n", myframe
print "Top 10 offending CVEs, Vulnerability and Count: \n"
print myframe['CVE_ID'].value_counts()
```

The last line prints out 2 columns: one of CVEs, and one of how many times it occurred.  But I want to print out something like this, where it maintains a link between the CVE and the Vulnerability Name (seen in the middle column):

```
Top 10 offending CVEs, Vulnerability and Count:
CVE-2017-1113   Java Update 1     3
CVE-2017-1114   Java Update 2     3
...etc...
```

How do I do that? Everything I do keeps throwing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: Changed so that in output have column name access**

**(Note the addition of `as_index=False` and `.reset_index` in [1] See sources 5 and 6**

[1] First `groupby` on `CVE_ID` column and use `size`:

```
counts = myframe.groupby(['CVE_ID','VulnName','ServerOwner'], as_index=False).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()


ServerOwner         CVE_ID       VulnName  Alice  Bob  Carol
0            CVE-2017-1111  Java Update 1      1    1      0
1            CVE-2017-1112  Java Update 2      1    1      0
2            CVE-2017-1113  Java Update 3      1    1      1
3            CVE-2017-1114        Adobe 1      1    1      1
4            CVE-2017-1115       Chrome 1      1    0      1
5            CVE-2017-1116       Chrome 2      0    0      1
6            CVE-2017-1117       Chrome 3      0    0      1
```

[2] Then sum over the Alice, Bob and Carol column to get:

```
counts['Count'] = counts[['Alice','Bob','Carol']].sum(axis=1)

ServerOwner         CVE_ID       VulnName  Alice  Bob  Carol  Count
0            CVE-2017-1111  Java Update 1      1    1      0      2
1            CVE-2017-1112  Java Update 2      1    1      0      2
2            CVE-2017-1113  Java Update 3      1    1      1      3
3            CVE-2017-1114        Adobe 1      1    1      1      3
4            CVE-2017-1115       Chrome 1      1    0      1      2
5            CVE-2017-1116       Chrome 2      0    0      1      1
6            CVE-2017-1117       Chrome 3      0    0      1      1
```

[3] Then delete name columns using `df.drop` on `names`:

```
counts.drop(['Carol','Bob','Alice'],inplace=True,axis=1)

ServerOwner         CVE_ID       VulnName  Count
0            CVE-2017-1111  Java Update 1      2
1            CVE-2017-1112  Java Update 2      2
2            CVE-2017-1113  Java Update 3      3
3            CVE-2017-1114        Adobe 1      3
4            CVE-2017-1115       Chrome 1      2
5            CVE-2017-1116       Chrome 2      1
6            CVE-2017-1117       Chrome 3      1
```

[4] Then you use `sort_values` on the `sum` column:

```
counts.sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False, inplace=True)

ServerOwner         CVE_ID       VulnName  Count
2            CVE-2017-1113  Java Update 3      3
3            CVE-2017-1114        Adobe 1      3
0            CVE-2017-1111  Java Update 1      2
1            CVE-2017-1112  Java Update 2      2
4            CVE-2017-1115       Chrome 1      2
5            CVE-2017-1116       Chrome 2      1
6            CVE-2017-1117       Chrome 3      1
```

**Combined:**

```
counts = myframe.groupby(['CVE_ID','VulnName','ServerOwner'], as_index=False).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
counts['Count'] = counts[['Alice','Bob','Carol']].sum(axis=1)
counts.drop(['Carol','Bob','Alice'],inplace=True,axis=1)
counts.sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False, inplace=True)

print "The dataframe: \n", myframe
print "Top 10 offending CVEs, Vulnerability and Count: \n"
print counts

Top 10 offending CVEs, Vulnerability and Count: 

ServerOwner         CVE_ID       VulnName  Count
2            CVE-2017-1113  Java Update 3      3
3            CVE-2017-1114        Adobe 1      3
0            CVE-2017-1111  Java Update 1      2
1            CVE-2017-1112  Java Update 2      2
4            CVE-2017-1115       Chrome 1      2
5            CVE-2017-1116       Chrome 2      1
6            CVE-2017-1117       Chrome 3      1
```

If needed, Can use `reset_index()` to reset index at this point.

Edit: In response to comment about `serverOwner` index, you can reset index, drop old index, and rename new index:

```
counts.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)
counts.index.names = ['index']
```

Gives:

```
ServerOwner         CVE_ID       VulnName  Count
index                                           
0            CVE-2017-1113  Java Update 3      3
1            CVE-2017-1114        Adobe 1      3
2            CVE-2017-1111  Java Update 1      2
3            CVE-2017-1112  Java Update 2      2
4            CVE-2017-1115       Chrome 1      2
5            CVE-2017-1116       Chrome 2      1
6            CVE-2017-1117       Chrome 3      1
```

(The `ServerOwner` name remains as a remnant of the original `groupby` command to detail which column was used.)

Sources for this answer:

> [1]
>   [Groupby value counts on the dataframe pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132742/groupby-value-counts-on-the-)
>   dataframe-pandas
>
> [2]
>   [Pandas: sum DataFrame rows for given columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748683/pandas-sum-dataframe-rows-for-given-columns)
>
> [3]
>   [Delete column from pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe)
>
> [4]
>   [python, sort descending dataframe with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988873/python-sort-descending-dataframe-with-pandas)
>
> [5]
>   [Converting a Pandas GroupBy object to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe)
>
> [6]
>   [How to GroupBy a Dataframe in Pandas and keep Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569549/how-to-groupby-a-dataframe-in-pandas-and-keep-columns)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the first ServerOwner column and how do you get rid of it?  I cant just show the CVE_ID, VulnName and Count columns.  Is ServerOwner a new name for the index?

Comment: I think it is. If you do `reset_index()` it will add on another index column but `ServerOwner` will still remain. I think it's because of the use of `group by` and making it equal to a new dataframe object: I'm not sure if this is technically the correct way to save it, might be a bit sketchy. Sorry i cant be more help now - will take a look in the morning (bit late here). But yes, i think at some stage it interprets `Server owner` as your index. You could try dropping that column at different points in the process using `df.drop` and see if that gets rid of it.

Comment: @user3688402 See my edit for index solution. Many thanks for upvoting and accepting. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` to append `value_counts`

```
myframe.join(myframe['CVE_ID'].value_counts().rename('Count'), on='CVE_ID')

           CVE_ID    Server ServerOwner       VulnName  Count
0   CVE-2017-1111  Server_1       Alice  Java Update 1      2
1   CVE-2017-1112  Server_1       Alice  Java Update 2      2
2   CVE-2017-1113  Server_1       Alice  Java Update 3      3
3   CVE-2017-1114  Server_1       Alice        Adobe 1      3
4   CVE-2017-1115  Server_1       Alice       Chrome 1      2
5   CVE-2017-1111  Server_2         Bob  Java Update 1      2
6   CVE-2017-1112  Server_2         Bob  Java Update 2      2
7   CVE-2017-1113  Server_2         Bob  Java Update 3      3
8   CVE-2017-1114  Server_2         Bob        Adobe 1      3
9   CVE-2017-1113  Server_3       Carol  Java Update 3      3
10  CVE-2017-1114  Server_3       Carol        Adobe 1      3
11  CVE-2017-1115  Server_3       Carol       Chrome 1      2
12  CVE-2017-1116  Server_3       Carol       Chrome 2      1
13  CVE-2017-1117  Server_3       Carol       Chrome 3      1
```

If you want to limit it to the top n, (my example shows 2), use `head` and `how='inner'`

```
myframe.join(
    myframe['CVE_ID'].value_counts().head(2).rename('Count'),
    on='CVE_ID', how='inner')

           CVE_ID    Server ServerOwner       VulnName  Count
2   CVE-2017-1113  Server_1       Alice  Java Update 3      3
7   CVE-2017-1113  Server_2         Bob  Java Update 3      3
9   CVE-2017-1113  Server_3       Carol  Java Update 3      3
3   CVE-2017-1114  Server_1       Alice        Adobe 1      3
8   CVE-2017-1114  Server_2         Bob        Adobe 1      3
10  CVE-2017-1114  Server_3       Carol        Adobe 1      3
```

Comment: Man, there is always a super simple one line way to do things, nice.

Comment: Do you not need to reduce the `CVE_ID` column so that you are not showing repeated ID's? i.e. You have three `1113` rows, when only one is required, as it is the count that is required, not the owner name?