# Splitting the output obtained by Counter in Python and pushing it to Excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, split, counter

I am using the counter function to count every word of the description of 20000 products and see how many times this word repeats like 'pipette' repeats 1282 times.To do this i have split a column A into many columns P,Q,R,S,T,U & V

```
df["P"] = df["A"].str.split(n=10).str[0]
df["Q"] = df["A"].str.split(n=10).str[1]
df["R"] = df["A"].str.split(n=10).str[2]
df["S"] = df["A"].str.split(n=10).str[3]
df["T"] = df["A"].str.split(n=10).str[4]
df["U"] = df["A"].str.split(n=10).str[5]
df["V"] = df["A"].str.split(n=10).str[6]
```

[This shows the splitted products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwEyb.jpg)

And the i am individually counting all of the columns and then add them to get the total number of words.

```
d = Counter(df['P'])
e = Counter(df['Q'])
f = Counter(df['R'])
g = Counter(df['S'])
h = Counter(df['T'])
i = Counter(df['U'])
j = Counter(df['V'])
m = d+e+f+g+h+i+j 
print(m)
```

[This is the image of the output i obtained on using counter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjv6N.jpg)

Now i want to transfer the output into a excel sheet with the Keys in one column and the Values in another.

Am i using the right method to do so? If yes how shall i push them into different columns.

Note: Length of each key is different

Also i wanna make all the items of column 'A' into lower case so that the counter does not repeat the items. How shall I go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been learning python for just a couple of months but I'll give it a shot. I'm sure there are some better ways to perform that same action. Maybe we both can learn something from this question. Let me know how this turns out. GoodLuck

```
import pandas as pd
num = len(m.keys())  
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Key', 'Value']
for i,j,k in zip(range(num), m.keys(), m.values()):
    df.loc[i] = [j, k]

df.to_csv('Your_Project.csv')
```

Comment: i had to create a dict named d just to be sure this works, jut replace d with m and this should work

Comment: I also feel like pandas could offer you an easier time dealing with such application like finding the number of word repetition, You should diffidently explore pandas

Comment: Hey i have two sets of keys and values when i execute them together oly on set of keys and values comes in my excel sheet.Wat shall i do? should it be done separately?

Comment: what do you mean by two sets of keys and values exactly?

Comment: like 'm' i have one more counter called 'single' and i want to place both their keys and values in the same excel sheet

Comment: you have to concatenate the two data frames then apply the same for loop on the concatenated data frame. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: Hey thank you that was perfect. Now how shall i but the values and their respective keys in the descending order ?

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)

Comment: Hey what about the descending order ? any idea?

Comment: Use the sort method of pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988873/python-sort-descending-dataframe-with-pandas