# sort out column of pandas dataframe by highest negative values first

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I want to sort out the column of the pandas dataframe which (includes floating numbers) by the highest negative values first.
for example
i have df["values"]=[0.00378,00878,-0.001,-0.00487]
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python, sort descending dataframe with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988873/python-sort-descending-dataframe-with-pandas)

Comment: it give positive number first. i need negatives. @roganjosh

Answer (score 0):

```
df["values"].sort_values(reverse=True)
```

^ This will sort the list in the descending order (largest number to smallest)

```
df["values"]. sort_values()
```

^ This will sort the list in the ascending order (smallest number to largest)

The smallest numbers there include negatives. However, if you're trying to only sort through negative numbers, you can filter the list for <0 and then sort in the second approach listed here (without including the reverse parameter).

Comment: more info here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort

Comment: getting error "series" object has not attribute "sort".

Comment: @ZamanAzam looks like sort() was deprecated and is now sort_values(). Give that a try. I updated the original answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think this has ever worked. `ascending=False` is the argument. Why are you guessing?

Comment: @roganjosh it does work. I wasn't guessing. Here's more info for you to review. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: That's for python _lists_. This is a Series

Comment: Yes that is for lists. If you want to sort a series, it uses  Series.sort_values(axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind=’quicksort’, na_position=’last’) I think we are saying the same thing and we agree on the differences between series and list. More details here for zaman to review https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-sort_values/amp